# $k$-connectedness graph checking in MATLAB

Tags: graph-theory, matlab, connectedness

A graph $G$ is said to be $k$-connected (or $k$-vertex connected, or $k$-point connected) if there does not exist a set of $k$-$1$ vertices whose removal disconnects the graph, i.e., the vertex connectivity of $G$ is $\geq k$. Therefore, a connected graph is $1$-connected, and a biconnected graph is $2$-connected.

Could anyone provide MATLAB code to check that a given graph is $k$-connected or not?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/472287/19341) could help...

Comment: Should this be posted on StackOverflow instead?